# Extending BaseAdapter, when does the view become null?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

I found a code that extends BaseAdapter

> ```
>         public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
>
>             if (view == null) {
>                 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
>                 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
>             }
>     }
>
>  TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_string_data);
>         textView.setText(dataModel.getName());
> ```

my question is when `view == null` ?

why we need the code  `if (view == null) {`}

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView typically contain more data then the number of displayed rows. If the user scrolls the list then rows and their associated Views will be scrolled out of the visible area. The Java objects which represents the rows can be reused for newly visible rows.

If Android determines that a View which represents a row is not visible anymore it allows the getView() method to reuse it via the convertView parameter.

A performance optimized adapter assigns the new data to the convertView. This avoids inflating an XML file and creating new Java objects.

In case no View is available for reuse, Android will pass null to the convertView parameter. Therefore the adapter implementation need to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first item in the listView the View will be null. It needs to be inflated for the first item.

Please be free to ask any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Android re-cycles View objects to minimize object creation and memory usage.  The View that is passed to you will either be null, in which case you are expected to create it, or the view will be non-null which means it has been re-cycled.  Re-cycled views are ones that you may have created earlier, but can now be used for a different purpose.

A good example of this is a listview.  A list may have many elements, say 100.  The screen however may only display 10 items of the list.  Thus when you scroll the screen, views that were for items no longer on the screen may be passed to you for re-use.  This is re-cycling.

Answer (score 0):

For list view we have to provide view for each and every item, and also we have to fill contents also. In most cases the same view will be repeated in every item with different content. So at the first time in `getView` method we will check, if view is null then we should inflate a view and fill the contents and return. At second time the view will not be null. So you can reuse or provide different view.